# Make input to fill the remaining width of label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following in HTML:

- input inside label element (rather not use ids and label for)
- input should occupy 100% of whatever width is remaining

It shouldn't be that hard, but I've tried lots of approaches from other examples; using floats, overflow: hidden, limiting the height of surrounding elements, etc. Not having 100% width works too, but that's not an option.

The reason I rather not use label-for (which does work) is that there will be several identical input fields on the same page. They are rather complex so I create one manually and then clone it with jQuery N times, which then would break horribly if using IDs.

Basic starting point:

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<label>
  name:
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Prepared a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8uuhhcon/

Comment: what is ur question dn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **Flexbox**

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<label>name:
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Comment: Depending on your support for IE this may not work for you. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @CodingWithSpike This is a great solution why do you wanna support [outdated IE](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-ending-support-internet-explorer-8-9-10-next-week)? ...there is nothing about IE support in OP post

Comment: @Anonymous every company I've worked for or done consulting for in the last 3 years supports back to at least IE9, some still 8. Practically every enterprise company is still on IE of some form (and for some reason they don't listen to me when I tell them not to ;-) ). So basically any "at work" project usually has some level of IE support. IE11 (still supported) has pretty buggy flexbox. MS Edge finally works well with flexbox, but its only Win10, so not many people have it...

Comment: @CodingWithSpike Alright Sir ;) ...then this is for you - https://github.com/10up/flexibility

Comment: @Anonymous yeah that's an option too. Don't get me wrong, I didn't say "don't use this", I'm just putting the comment there that if there is a requirement to support IE<11 then this solution may not work. Better for someone to know this now rather than copy/paste it, only test in Chrome, send to production, and have unhappy IE customers. I was just making readers aware, not downvoting the answer.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike yeah sir you're right and I'm also trying to point out an option for that and I'm sorry if I sounded rude ;)

Comment: Love the simplicity of this answer, thank you! IE9 support is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you can wrap *name:* into a span or so, like `<span>name:</span>`, you can try the CSS table.

```css
label {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
span, input {
  display: table-cell;
}
span {
  width: 1%; /*give a small value*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*prevent wrapping i.e. "user name"*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*or top/bottom as needed*/
}
input {
  width: 99%; /*give a large value*/
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>name:</span>
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Comment: That does work, thanks! It is probably a bit more cross-compliant than using flexbox so can be useful for people who needs to support IE9, but in my particular case the simplicity of the Flexbox solution is overwhelming.