# How to set input width to fill rest of div and adjust dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I get an input thats sitting inline with a label to fill the rest of the width of the wrapping div container whos width changes dynamically based on the screen size/resize?

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="form-field sixcol">
    <label class="form-label>...</label>
    <input type="text">...</input>
</div>
```

My JavaScript is as follow:

```
function formFields()
{
    var formField = $('div.form-field').outerWidth();
    var formLabel = $('label.form-label').outerWidth();
    var formInput = formField - formLabel;

    $('input.form-input').css('width', formInput);
}
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    formFields();
    ...
});

$(document).resize(function(){
    formFields();
    ...
});
```

When I had the `formFields()` function print the sizes of each element to a `<p>` tag it was reporting the wrong width for the form-field element and thus was calculating the wrong size for the form-input. My labels and inputs both have a 1px border. Should I be using innerHeight()? Why is it not calculating correctly?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773798/make-input-to-fill-the-remaining-width-of-label/34773867#34773867

Comment: Use width() on formField and your code should work. The outerWidth() is not the same width the children can occupy(can't occupy padding space and border space).